# Trouble with Hibernate Entity in Play 2.4

Tags: java, hibernate, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to use JPA in Play 2.4, but it's flinging errors at every step of the way, none of which seem to be well documented.

I have a test Entity here:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="testit")
public class TestModel {

    @Id
    private long id;
    private String title;

    public TestModel(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return this.title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

Because I'm going to be frequently updating and creating entities, I'm using this property in `persistence.xml`:

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
```

And I'm trying to learn how to actually persist this entity.  Here's what I've got so far in one of my controllers:

```
@Transactional
public static Result runExperiment() {
    TestModel tester = new TestModel("testingasdf");
    JPA.em().persist(tester);
    return ok();
}
```

When I ran this the first time, it worked just fine, and I verified the entry in the DB.  But when I run it a second time, I get the error message:

```
a.d.Dispatcher - EntityManager is closed
```

On a similar note, the examples I've seen have this notation on the id so that it doesn't frequently try to insert `0` as the id:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;
```

But when I try this, I get errors like this:

```
o.h.t.h.SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: drop table testit if exists
o.h.t.h.SchemaExport - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'if exists' at line 1
o.h.t.h.SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: create table testit (id bigint generated by default as identity, title varchar(255), primary key (id))
o.h.t.h.SchemaExport - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'generated by default as identity, title varchar(255), primary key (id))' at line 1
```

Honestly I'm getting a bit lost at this point trying to figure out how to even setup a simple entity like this.  All the suggestions around the web suggest using JPA rather than eBeans, but I dunno....

Comment: Have you tried to delete the existing tables manually before executing it again. Maybe there are some troubles while recreating the table.
edit: Please copy the full persistence.xml I assume you might have a dialect issue

Comment: @mh-dev: I just read your edit after posting the solution I found.  I was looking for several hours, but collecting my thoughts into this question apparently helped in the search.

Comment: Fine that you problem is solved. It happens often to find the solution on your own after asking someone external :)

Comment: @mh-dev:  Also, I'd be happy to accept an answer you write rather than my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the tutorial Play posts is specific to their H2 database system.  As a noob, I missed the fact that you need to tell Hibernate what dialect to use.  In the persistence.xml, I changed the dialect line to this:

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
```

Seems my problems are now solved.